# Why does CloudFront cache s3 object even though there aren't any cache settings?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a `CloudFront` distribution having `s3` bucket as an origin.

The distribution is using `Use Origin Cache Headers` setting.

The additional setting is like the below.

[image]

After that, I upload a file through `S3` console and try to get the file using `curl`.(of course, there is no `Cache-Control` metadata)

[image]

```
$ curl -X GET https://xxxxxxxxxxx/file -v
.
.
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
.
.
.
$ curl -X GET https://xxxxxxxxxxx/file -v
.
.
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront.
.
.
```

I expected that all requests should return `cache-miss` because there is no setting for the cache anywhere(CloudFront and S3 object metadata). However, as you can see, the second request is returning `cache-hit`.

Why does CloudFront cache it?

Is there any hidden default cache settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way the console presents this is admittedly very confusing and arguably not even "correct."

CloudFront always uses the origin cache headers **and** always uses a Min/Default/Max TTL.

**Use Origin Cache Headers** actually means *"Use Origin Cache Headers with standard CloudFront default and bounding values."*

**Customize** actually means *"Use Origin Cache Headers with custom CloudFront default and bounding values."*

So objects with no `Cache-Control` are cached for up to `Default TTL` -- 86400 seconds, by default.  If you don't want this behavior, switch to `Customize` and set `Default TTL` to the value you want CloudFront to use as an object TTL if no `Cache-Control` value is privided in the headers.

If `Cache-Control` *is* present, CloudFront ignores `Default TTL` and instead uses the bounding values `Minimim TTL` and `Maximum TTL` to determine whether it should use the origin's `Cache-Control` values internally, or override them.  If out of range, CloudFront adjusts its internal timer so that the object's TTL is in the range >= `Minimum TTL` (default 0 seconds) and <= `Maximum TTL` (1 year) reducing too-large values to max and increasing too-small values up to min.  If the `Cache-Control` value is already within that range, the value from `Cache-Control` is used as is.  Either way, CloudFront does not actually modify the `Cache-Control` header itself.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html

Comment: I am seeing behavior that contradicts this. I created a CF distro with default settings (I.e. Object Caching setting = Use Origin Cache Headers) and my S3 origin is not attaching any cache headers. Yet, not only does CF seem to cache the file, it isn't even expiring after 24 hours since I updated the file in S3 more than 24 hours ago and CF is still not picking it up. Any ideas?